# opening a new gui from the gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

**updated code as per below comments**

I'm struggling to get my top level to open on button press!

I've scanned the code on here but don't seem to be able to get a woking solution. My latest error is:

> AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'unavail'

```
    from tkinter import *
from ScheduleApi import flightData
import config
from itinerary import fltCreate

class FrontEnd:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.grid()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Create Itinerary", command=self.ItinBuilder)
        self.greet_button.grid(row=1)

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.grid(row=2)



    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

    def ItinBuilder(self):
        self = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.title ("Please build your itinerary")

        self.addflt_button = Button(self.master, text="add flights", command=fltCreate)
        self.addflt_button.grid(row=1)

        self.addfhtl_button = Button(self.master, text="add hotel", command=self.master.unavail)
        self.addflt_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.addfmsc_button = Button(self.master, text="add misc item", command=self.master.unavail)
        self.addflt_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.prvitin_button = Button(self.master, text="preview", command=self.master.unavail)
        self.addflt_button.grid(row=2, column=1)



    def unavail(self,  Toplevel):
        print("Function not yet available.")



root = Tk()
my_gui = FrontEnd(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `FrontEnd` class does not derive from any Tkinter class, and therefore is not any sort of widget.  That's a perfectly valid way of structuring a Tkinter program, but it does mean that you cannot pass an instance of this class as the first parameter for any widgets you create (as you're doing with `self.addflt_button`, for example) - you have to pass an actual widget, `self.newWindow` perhaps.

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand. When I run ItinBuilder my first line is to pass the widget
    

    self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)

Comment: @user3207324, You need to pass a valid tkinter widget as first argument to any tkinter widget, which means pass `self.master` or `self.newWindow` to the widgets created in `ItinBuilder` function instead of `self`. In your case, when you pass `self` to it, it tries to treat `FrontEnd` object as a tkinter widget and fails.

Comment: Thanks for your help both, I seem to be getting there. I seem to be getting there, I have 2 problems still remaining (sorry for being a pain, I'm a complete tkinter novice!)
ItinBuilder is struggling to pull unavail, even though it's defined in the FrontEnd class. Also it's getting as far as to atleast create the add flight button now, but it's placing the button in the main GUI, not the new window. updated code below:

[[...]
def ItinBuilder(self):
        self = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.title ("Please build your itinerary")]

Comment: **UPDATED CODE ABOVE**

Answer (score 0):

Please change your function `ItinBuilder` to this. I hope this is what you expect.

```
def ItinBuilder(self):
    self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
    self.newWindow.title ("Please build your itinerary")

    self.addflt_button = Button(self.newWindow, text="add flights", command=fltCreate)
    self.addflt_button.grid(row=0)

    self.addfhtl_button = Button(self.newWindow, text="add hotel", command=self.master.unavail)
    self.addfhtl_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

    self.addfmsc_button = Button(self.newWindow, text="add misc item", command=self.master.unavail)
    self.addfmsc_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    self.prvitin_button = Button(self.newWindow, text="preview", command=self.master.unavail)
    self.prvitin_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

The `add flights` button is in main GUI because you passed the reference to your main window `self.master` as first argument(called parent in tkinter) in your code.

Only `add_flights` button is seen and not others because you called `grid` method only for `self.addflt_button` and not for other buttons(missed to change variable names in other calls I guess).